# Atomic measure on generators

Tags: measure-theory

In measure theory, I've sometimes seen arguments of the sort of the following, if I'm interpreting it correctly.

> Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space where the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ is countably generated. Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\Sigma$, and suppose that for a set of generators $\{S_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $\Sigma$ we have that for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mu(S_i)\in\{0,1\}$.
> Then for all measurable sets $A\in\Sigma$, $\mu(A)\in\{0,1\}$ as well.

First of all, is this correct? If so:

- How can we prove it?
- Is the "countably generated" assumption necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as "always" when you're proving things about the $\sigma$-algebra generated by some family of sets: Let $\mathcal A=\{E\in\Sigma:\mu(E)\in\{0,1\}\}$. Show that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Now since $$\{S_i\}\subset\mathcal A\subset\Sigma,$$the definition of "$\Sigma$ is generated by $\{S_i\}$" says that $\mathcal A=\Sigma$.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{A}$, as you constructed, always a $\sigma$-algebra? How can one prove that?

Comment: @geodude Do you know the definition of "$\sigma$-algebra"? It's trivial to verify that $\mathcal A$ satisfies the definition.

Comment: Why is it closed under countable unions?

Comment: @geodude [sigh...] Say $E_1,E_2,\dots\in\mathcal A$, $E=\bigcup E_j$. If $\mu(E_j)=0$ for all $j$ then $\mu(E)=0$, so $E\in\mathcal A$. If otoh there exists $j$ with $\mu(E_j)=1$ then $\mu(E_j)\le\mu(E)\le\mu(X)$ shows that $\mu(E)=1$, so $E\in\mathcal A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra generated by $\{S_i\}$: its easy to see that its sets have measure $\{0,1\}$.
Since $\mu$ is a probability measure, we know that its extension from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\Sigma$ is: $\mu(A)=\inf\{\sum A_i:A\subseteq \cup A_i; A_i\in \mathcal{A}\}$. Being the infimum of integers, it must be an integer ($\le 1$ as it is a probability) and the result follows.

Comment: How do you show that $\mu$ is $\{0,1\}$ on the whole of $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: $\mathcal{A}$ is composed of $X,\emptyset$ and of finite intersections of elements of $\{S_i\}\cup \{S_i^c\}$. You just need to prove that for finite intersections the measure is $\{0,1\}$. By induction, it suffices to prove the result for the intersection of $2$ elements. If one of them has measure $0$, the result is trivial. If that is not the case, note that $\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A)-\mu(A\cap B^c)=\mu(A)=1$, since $\mu(B^c)=0$ and we are done.

Comment: If the downvoter would care to explain what's wrong with my answer, I'm open to suggestions.